# How to add product images to packing list?

Tags: magento2, packing-slip

I currently use the packing list from Magento but I have trouble with not having the product pictures and/or SKU on it. 
Can somebody tell me how and/or which code I would need to use to add those to my packing list?
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

[image]